# Supply a string that is not null terminated to strcpy

Tags: c, string, copy

Here is the code

```
smem_dmp(char *name, char content[])
{                     
        int i;
        int len = strlen(content);       

        printf("%s\n\n", name);

        for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
             printf("%c\t%p\n", content[i], &content[i] );     
        }

        printf("Done\n\n");
}

print_bar()
{
     printf("********************************************************************\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char a[16];
    char b[16];


    strcpy(a, "abcdefghijklmnop");
    printf("a = %s\nb = %s\n\n",a,b);

    smem_dmp("A", a);
    smem_dmp("B", b);

    print_bar();

    strcpy(b, "ABCDEFGHILKLMNOP");
    printf("a = %s\nb = %s\n\n",a,b);

    smem_dmp("A", a);
    smem_dmp("B", b);

    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

From looking at where a and b reside in memory I have worked out what is happening. The string copied to b is not null terminated. This is causing the contents of a to be removed because b is located (0028FF20) before a in memory (0028FF30).

What is happening? Does strcpy(b,"string") not stop until it has gone through all the memory on the stack frame variables? Sorry if I am not using the correct terminology. :)

Comment: Your array `a` is too small. It needs at least 17 elements.

Comment: Thanks. I know. This is more about understanding security than fixing code.

Comment: Yes it will keep on copying bytes until it either gets to a zero byte in whatever random memory it is accessing or it reaches inaccessable memory and causes a memory fault. If the layout is as you say it will eventually scribble all over the other string if it gets there before it crashes. None of that is defined by any standard though, it's just what common implementations will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is happening? Does `strcpy(b,"string")` not stop until it has gone through all the memory on the stack frame variables?

`strcpy` copies bytes until it finds a 0-byte in the source. That is copied to the destination, and then `strcpy` returns. (If the destination isn't big enough to hold the source including the 0-terminator, the behaviour is undefined, but unless you get a segmentation fault, that is what in practice you can rely on happening.)

So

```
strcpy(b, "ABCDEFGHILKLMNOP");
```

copies 17 bytes - the 16 letters and the 0-terminator - from the string literal to the array `b`, which only contains 16 elements. That means the 0-terminator is written one element past the end of the array `b`. In your situation, that is the first byte in `a`, and the `strcpy(b, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP");` effectively makes `a` contain an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

the size of `"abcdefghijklmnop"` is 16 and the size of your `a` array is 16 it should be 17 (16 + 1 null terminator charachter)